# App throwing variable reference error when variable is a function argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am building a backend in the MEAN stack and have come across an issue. The point of the app is simple: Upload a file and it saves it to the server. However, I am stumbled upon a problem. The code breaks and throws the following error in the console when I hit the "Submit" button:

```
<h1>photo is not defined</h1>
<h2></h2>
<pre>ReferenceError: photo is not defined
    at \routes\index.js:32:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at \node_modules\express-jwt\lib\index.js:112:9
    at \node_modules\jsonwebtoken\index.js:98:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)</pre>
```

The following is my `angularApp.js` file:

```
app.factory('photos', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = { photos: [] };
  o.create = function(photo) {
    return $http.post('/photos', photo, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      o.photos.push(data);
    }).error(function(a) {
      console.log(a);
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'photos',
'auth',
function($scope, photos, auth){
  $scope.photos = photos.photos;
  $scope.addPhoto = function(){
    photos.create();
  };
}]);
```

`index.ejs` code:

```
<form ng-submit="addPhoto()">
  <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
  <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

And here is `routes\index.js`

```
router.post('/photos', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var dirname = require('path').dirname(__dirname);
  var filename = req.files.file.name;
  var path = req.files.file.path;
  var type = req.files.file.mimetype;

  var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(dirname + '/' + path);
  var conn = req.conn;
  var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
  Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);

  var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: filename
  });
  read_stream.pipe(writestream);

  photo.save(function(err, photo){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(photo);
  });
});
```

What I have understood is that the code breaks running the `o.create` function, but I am not sure why it's unable to find `photo`, when that's one of the function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code you've posted for `routes/index.js`, the line

```
photo.save(...
```

is using a variable `photo` that was not previously defined in the current or any parent scope.